# How to handle user permissions changing on active JWT?

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies

I have an application that includes both frontend and backend, a user can authenticate, and the username and their permission is encoded in the JWT token I store in the cookie.
In the frontend, I need to show data for the user if they're logged in (using the cookie). Admins can change the permissions user has (downgrade them), and I need to reflect this in the frontend (they won't be allowed to see certain functionalities in the frontend). If I'm using the cookie to get the username and their permissions and its token hasn't expired yet, I might show them secured actions that only admins are allowed to preform in the frontend.

Is there a way to bypass this other than checking the user permission in the DB on each refresh?
I'm using react and express js

currently I'm checking the user permission in the DB on each refresh but I don't think it's the optimal approach.

Comment: What you're looking for is called _token revocation_ - and while it's possible to implement, there are no "good" solutions, only compromises - this is why when you're using a stateless bearer-token scheme (like JWT) it's important to use short-lived access-tokens that expire between 5 minutes to 1 hour after issuance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any good way to implement what you want. If you want to track for which user the permissions have been changed, there is no way to do this without managing some kind of state on your server. And that breaks the whole gist of using JWT tokens